# IE & DailyMotion streaming in iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, streaming, dailymotion-api

I have bunch of videos on daily motion to stream it in my webservice.
Service is running on secure HTTP.

I got generated iframes to use for HTTPS.
Everything works great on Chrome & Firefox.

The problems are starting on IE (v.11).
Firstly it blocks content and it's saying that now is displayed only secure content.
There is a button to 'show all content'.. after clicking I am getting this in iframe:

"Sorry, something went wrong...
Please refresh this page or come back later."

Looks like an error coming from Daily motion.. however I don't have such problems with others browsers..

Any ideas? I checked console and debugger in IE but there was nothing special.
If I am playing the video directly from the URL, it runs.

I have other service which runs on HTTP and iframe generated for HTTPS - streaming works.

I have totally no idea what is disabling correct streaming on HTTPS.

I will be grateful for any tips! =D

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I am testing a few more ideas I got..
if nothing will work I will try to publish here something more! =D

Comment: this line was disabling proper streaming in IE:
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
.. case solved ;-)

Comment: hi @Kamil can you add your last comment in an answer if it solved your problem, it will help other person from the community to benefit from your answer

Answer (score 0):

this line was disabling proper streaming in IE v11:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

.. case solved ;-)